# IIS timeout for active connections

Tags: iis, .net

Is it possible to set a timeout for active connections in IIS?  I know that you can set a timeout for idle connections.

What leads me to ask this question is a scenario with a load balancer in front of a bunch of nodes running IIS.  In order to support painless declustering of nodes without forcible disconnects on active connections we'd like to enforce a timeout on all active connections.  Given this we could remove the node from the cluster and then wait the duration of the timeout for traffic to drain.

As it is clients have to be written to play nice with our load balanced setup by controlling their connection lease.  This is obviously possible but kind of a pain.  If we could control it server-side clients would not have to care about it.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you kill all the connections now or after a timeout, you'll still be killing active connections and it'll be disruptive for your users. You are probably after something else (e.g. stop accepting new connections but keep the old ones running until they finish)

Comment: Isn't there something you can send in the response header that instructs the client to close the connection?  Perhaps I'm mistaken.  Obviously I don't want to kill the connection.  I'm looking for some way to have the server notify the client to terminate the connection.  If that doesn't exist than so be it.

Comment: Close the connection based on what? After all the information has been sent? TCP does that by default. You might want to stop receiving new connections and just wait for the old ones to end.

Comment: Are you familiar with what happens when you set the "Connection" http request header to "Close"?  After the request is complete the server terminates the connection (at least when using IIS).   System.Net.WebClient will send this header when a ServicePoint connection reaches it's ConnectionLeaseTimeout.  I was wondering if there was something similar that can be initiated from the server side.  Perhaps a response header telling the client that the connection is about to be terminated so it can react appropriately and initiate a new one.

Comment: I see what you mean now. No, I don't know of something similar, but if you use HTTP/1.0 you can only send one request per connection and that can be controlled from the server side. I can't recommend it though as it'll potentiallu slow down your site's load time.

Comment: Yeah, that definitely won't work for us.   We are in control of the client code for most of our traffic, but for the remainder I guess we'll have to instruct people consuming the service to make their clients tolerant to connection termination.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could think to pull this off is to have a batch or scheduled task that turns off the IIS service so you can do what you needed to do. That same object can then turn it back on as well.